# Ways to make the LINQ performance better

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Question is: Show the names of all employees and the resulting salaries if only employees working on the 'ProductX' project are given a 10% raise.

This works fine:

```
var data_18 = db.employees.Select(e1 => new
    {
        e1.FNAME,
        e1.SSN,
        SALARY = db.works_on.Where(w => w.ESSN == e1.SSN)
                            .Join(db.projects.Where(p => p.PNAME == "ProductX"), w => w.PNO, p => p.PNUMBER, (w, p) => 1).Count() == 0 ? e1.SALARY : e1.SALARY * 1.1
    }).ToList();
```

This needs a grouping I couldn't make yet.

```
var data_18_1 = db.employees
    .Join(db.works_on, e1 => e1.SSN, wo => wo.ESSN, (e1, wo) => new
    {   
        e1,
        wo
    }).Join(db.projects, x => x.wo.PNO, p => p.PNUMBER, (g, p) => new
    {
        g.e1.FNAME,
        g.e1.LNAME,
        SALARY = (p.PNAME == "ProductX" ? g.e1.SALARY * 1.1 : g.e1.SALARY)
    }).ToList();
```

I need help on how I make the 2nd 1 grouping or fix the top 1 so it gives a better select query in sql side since current 1 gives 1 thats far from good.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is wrong with the first query? If you are using EF, why are you not using navigation properties? Your second one doesn't seem like it will produce the right answer to me. Consider using `GroupJoin` rather than `Join`.

Comment: @NetMage I am new on ET so going to check about navigation. First 1 works but the query it produces isn’t good so wondered if it can be optimised. 2nd part doesn’t work as i stated so it doesn’t produce right answer yes. Can you give an example on how group join going to help ? Thank you.